# Convert <type 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer'> to list

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to list a dataproc cluster to get the worker node names. The datatype that the code is returning is  and I want to convert it to list

```
for cluster in dataproc_cluster_client.list_clusters(project_id, region):
    if cluster.cluster_name == 'test':
        print(type(cluster.config.worker_config.instance_names))
        print(type(cluster.config.master_config.instance_names))
```

Answer (score 12):

list(cluster.config.worker_config.instance_names) to convert to a Python list

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
[_ for _ in cluster.config.worker_config.instance_names]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, conversion to numpy array can be done as simply as:

`x = np.array(proto_object)`